# In Android EditText, is there a way to force every character to be lowercase?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I found a lot of solutions here to make EditText display characters in caps, however, is there a way to do the opposite and limit it to lowercase characters only?

Using `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz"` "works" but it simply ignores characters *not* in the list with no feedback. I want it so that even when the user inputs an uppercase character, it is converted to a lowercase character.

It can ignore numbers, that is fine.

Comment: @MaxAves YES!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Max linked to a Java solution but here is a kotlin one:

```kotlin
edit_text.filters += object : AllCaps() {
            override fun filter(
                source: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                end: Int,
                dest: Spanned,
                dstart: Int,
                dend: Int
            ): CharSequence {
                return source.toString().toLowerCase()
            }
        }
```